# Building a vertical crossfilter chart

Tags: visualization, d3.js, crossfilter

Starting from the basic [Crossfilter](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/) example, i'd like to create an alternate visualization that displays the barcharts vertically instead of horizontally.  That is, essentially flip the axies of the barchart.

It's easy enough to modify the [original](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/blob/gh-pages/index.html) `barChart` function to swap the bars in the chart.  I've been able to do that with these following changes:

```
var width = x.range()[1],
    height = y.range()[0];
```

Becomes

```
var width = x.range()[1],
    height = y.range()[0];
```

and in the nested `barPath` method

```
path.push("M", x(d.key), ",", height, "V", y(d.value), "h9V", height);
```

becomes

```
path.push("M", 0, ",", x(d.key), "h", y(d.value), "v9H", 0);
```

These minor changes get the bars printed nicely, but it doesn't handle the x axis with it's ticks, nor does it handle the selection brushes.  Is it possible to flip the brushes on their sides?  If so, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

An easiest way would be to rotate the "g" container of each chart by 90 in chart().

Something like this:

```
g = div.append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left +
margin.right).attr("height", height + margin.top +
margin.bottom).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" +
margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"+ "**rotate(90)**");
```